# Is even a preposition/conjunction?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

> No one can do it , **even him**.

I've always thought that "even" can function as both preposition and conjunction in that it can be followed by noun phrases or dependent clauses. But dictionaries only say it's an adverb ? And for my example above, what exactly do you call the boldface text in relation to the clause (adverbial...)?

Comment: I would use "**not** even him"

Answer (score 4):

The definition of adverb from Webster's College (1) and Collins (2; quoted from definition 1a), via [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adverb):

> 1. a member of a class of words functioning as modifiers of verbs, adjectives, other adverbs, or clauses, typically expressing some relation of place, time, manner, degree, means, cause, result, exception, etc. ...
> 2. a word or group of words that serves to modify a whole sentence, a verb, another adverb, or an adjective

Modifying sentences as above is the function of *even*, thus it's an adverb.

It's not a conjunction because *even* doesn't group or join things together. It neither defines collections (e.g. *A, B or C*) nor connects two parts of a sentence (e.g. *I went to the store and bought some things*). I would even go farther and say it separates things, by using emphasis to make them stand out. A verb, quality or condition marked with *even* is notably different from the norm; *even* provides emphasis, not connectivity. You can have conjunction phrases which include even, such as *even so*, but in these cases *even* serves to modify the meaning of the actual conjunction. If you remove *even* from such a conjunction, it will still be grammatical (though it may no longer be semantically correct). *Even* doesn't join a clause to the rest of the sentence; it *modifies the meaning of the clause itself*.

*Even* may sometimes appear to function in a prepositional manner, just as it does in your example. But it's not a preposition, because it doesn't require a noun target (or any target, *even*) and it serves to modify a clause, not introduce one. In these cases, *even* stands at the beginning of an adverbial phrase. It's grammatical and sensible to use a naked, targetless *even* at the end of a sentence, but it's generally not to do so with a preposition. Observe:

> 1. We all went, even Steve.
> 2. We all went, even.

The two meanings are marginally different, but the general sense remains the same with or without *Steve*. Everyone was able to go, and this was unexpected or difficult to accomplish. Calling out *Steve* serves to indicate of the precise level of difficulty; presumably he is particularly unavailable or reluctant relative to the rest of the group.

> *No one can do it, **even him.***
>   And for my example above, what exactly do you call the boldface text ... ?

I'd call it a clause functioning as an adverb. The clause emphasizes the whole sentence (*no one can do it*), by using whoever *he* is as a marker of difficulty, just as with *Steve* in my example.

As an aside, this sentence is unsemantic, because *he* is a member of the group who are unable to perform the action. But the negative is applied to the subject rather than the verb, so this suggests *he can do it*, because *no one* is contrasted with *him*. Adding *not* before *even* will fix this problem, by keeping *him* inside the negated group.

Comment: Oh, That makes sense +1

Answer (score 0):

Even is an adverb when used in this context. See [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/even) or pretty much any dictionary. Some would argue that it is an adjective because it modifies a pronoun/noun, but if [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) is to be believed, then adverbs have no problem being adnominal. (However, wikipedia appears to be the only source with this viewpoint.)